# Relation of c# name space and file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

How is a C# namespace related to the physical representation of the program in files and folders?

When one uses a using directive, e.g.:

```
using MyNameSpace;
```

Where does does the C# compiler look for that namespace? Is there some documentation which covers the relationship of logical entities like namespaces and classes with their physical representations?

My .csproj file just contains

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Nevertheless it seems to compile all .cs files in the project. I am using Visual Studio Code and want to understand the magic that is going on.

Comment: There is no relation. End of story

Comment: Of course it would be a good practice for you to maintain some relation. Otherwise, it may be more of a problem for you to find a namespace or class than for the compiler. :-)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy This does not answer my question.

Comment: @sakra which of your questions?

Comment: your compiler looks at ALL files represented in the .csproj file ... <Compile Include="<<<your filename here>>>.cs" />

Comment: Where does does the C# compiler look for that namespace?

Comment: it would look for it in any referenced dlls and the project that has that in the class. outside of that, there isn't any relationship.

Comment: in short... it does not look for a namespace... it takes all files referenced in the csproj and loads them... afterwards it looksup the namespace directives from what was loaded

Comment: Namespaces are a **logical** construct. Multiple assemblies may contain types that all belong to the same namespace. An assembly may contain types for multiple namespaces.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 the .csproj file does not reference any files at all.

Comment: open the file with notepad and search for "Compile Include="

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: Either your .sln has more than this .csproj or there is no C# code to be compiled and thus no namespaces or classes to be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page [Additions to the csproj format for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/csproj) from the .NET core guide explains that the SDK referenced in the .csproj file contains definitions of globbing expressions (i.e., `**/*.cs`) which are used to locate source files in the project.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Java, the compiler does not require the files to follow the same structure as the namespace, nor does it require the filename to match the class name.

I think it's still *good style* to name your files the same as the class name, which is what VisualStudio defaults to when you use the new class wizard.  If you create a class in a folder in your project, VisualStudio will also default to a namespace that combines the base namespace with the folder name.

Answer (score 2):

"Where does does the C# compiler look for that namespace?"
In every Reference added to the project. A lot of them are added Automatically. Keep in mind that using merely shields you from having to write the fully qualified name for every class in that namespace. It enabeles you to write "myClass1" instead of "MyNameSpace.myClass1" (Every. Single. Time). You may still ahve to write fully qualified names sometimes (like when you use more then one namespace with a timer class - there are 3 in .NET).

"Is there some documentation which covers the relationship of logical entities like namespaces and classes with their physical representations?"
You put some MSIL compiled code into your projeect reference. Then you can use all the namespaces defined in that compliation and all teh classes defined in those namespaces. Note that both .NET dll and .NET executeables are valid References. Internally a .NET execudetable is a .NET dll, with a manifest, bootstrap code and a "entry point" into the code.

Comment: Regarding the physical place: At least the .NET documentation lists exactly wich dll contains a certain class. For example, ExpandoObject(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) is in the Namespace System.Dynamic. In the file System.Core.dll.